# SwiftUI, @State fed from Struct, building an editor

Tags: swift, swiftui, struct, state

Ok, I couldn't find this exact problem in searching, so forgive me if I overlooked something deep in the bowels of searches.

**Premise**:
Existing system. Adding an editor. Data is passed around in Swift Structs, pulled and updated via existing REST API stuff. I don't have a lot of control over the upstream stuff. Or more accurately, I don't have the time to re-architect anything upstream at the moment (solo dev on a recently inherited project).

**Problem**:
As noted, the data is pushed around in structs. Here's a (pared-down) example:

```
struct Person: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let firstname: String
    let lastname: String
}
```

These are displayed and selectable in a View and the user can tap on one to selected it, and (presumably) display the editor. Navigating to the editor is the final model, but here in this example, I'm just shoving it into the single/main view for simplicity.

My editor receives the Person, copies the values into @State variables for display and editing and then when the user hits Save, the updates are pushed to the REST server, then the editor is dismissed, and the struct is replaced on the read-back/refresh, etc. Pretty normal workflow.

*Note: the save button and API code are not in this example to keep it lean and simple.*

However, in my editor, I'm copying the values from the passed-in Person struct and in the View's Init, you can verify the value changes (see Print statement there), but the actual view isn't updated. Presumably the body isn't redrawing?

I'm returning to SwiftUI after about a year completely buried in Python server side stuff, and I just can't believe I'm THIS rusty. I must be missing something simple.

What am I missing? (code follows)

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State private var selectedPerson: Person?
    
    // could also do this if optionals and nils are scary
    // @State private var selectedPerson: Person = Person(
    //    id: 0,
    //    firstname: "No one",
    //    lastname: "Selected"
    //) // or whatever
    
    
    // pretend these are populated from an API REST call 
    private var people: [Person] = [
        Person(id: 1, firstname: "Bob", lastname: "Bobberson"),
        Person(id: 2, firstname: "Joe", lastname: "Smith"),
        Person(id: 3, firstname: "Taylor", lastname: "Swift") // because apparently that's what you do now
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let sp = self.selectedPerson {
                Text("Selected: \(sp.firstname)")
                    .padding()
            } else {
                Text("No one is selected")
            }
            
            ScrollView {
                ForEach(people){ person in
                    Text(person.firstname)
                        .padding()
                        .onTapGesture {
                            selectedPerson = person
                        }
                } // all works as expected. Trouble starts below.


                if let _ = self.selectedPerson {
                    PersonEditor(person: selectedPerson!)
                }

                // or this if it's more desired or more "swifty"
                if let e = self.selectedPerson {
                    PersonEditor(person: e)
                }
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct PersonEditor: View {
    // this doesn't need to exist, just including for completeness.
    private var person: Person
    
    @State private var edtFirstname: String = ""
    @State private var edtLastname: String = ""
    
    init(person: Person){
        // this doesn't need to exist. included for completeness.
        self.person = person
        
        self._edtFirstname = State(wrappedValue: person.firstname)
        self._edtLastname = State(wrappedValue: person.lastname)
        // changing to initialValue to wrappedValue seems to not matter

        // this runs and prints correct.
        print("current first name is \(self.edtFirstname)")
        // so why does this show the fed-in value after setting the state
        // but the Text and TextField objects in the body do not?
        // suggests body isn't being called despite state changing.
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Editing \(person.firstname)") // this updates correctly (as expected)
            Text("Editing \(self.edtFirstname)") // this does not
            
            TextField("firstname", text: $edtFirstname) // this never changes despite init running
            TextField("lastname", text: $edtLastname) // this never changes despite init running
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine when I try it. I removed the duplicate attempts and some other relevant stuff but it works as expected. I kept the State(wrapped:) initialisers and remove the others. The Text fields updates properly nd using onChange to print the new value also confirms that it works. My guess is that you have gotten confused about which Text view is which because the first one doesn't and should not update when the first name is changed but the second one correctly does.

Comment: Also, the most swifty way is `if let selectedPerson {` :)

Comment: Weird and what the heck. Grrrr.... Here's what happens for me. 

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1whQBfwO-_LOfD2B1VFY7Bm6zjajxQcYn/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood your question. Now I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Notice that using State(wrappedValue is explicitly discouraged https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/state/wrappedvalue

Comment: Oh, in normal user code, for sure. In the init, though, you don't have much choice but to set the underlying _state value, so wrapped or initial are your options. (which always felt hackey to me). :\

Comment: Initial is the way to go not wrapped. If you make selectedPerson the id for the editor your issues will be “solved” it will force the view to be recreated.

Comment: You have to remember that in SwiftUI State determines the view identity. That is why it shouldn’t come from the parent. If it does you have to forcefully redraw the View. The init being called doesn’t mean that the Storage allocated by SwiftUI gets erased, it is meant to outlive a single instance of a View.

Comment: Holy crap; I didn't even think of using an .id on the editor. Resolved! Thank you so much!

Please add an official answer with this so I can mark it accepted, as well as making it clearer on future searches for folks.

".id(selectedPerson)" <-- that did it completely (when id isn't nil, so code accordingly).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `selectedPerson` the `id` for the editor.

```
if let selectedPerson {
      PersonEditor(person: selectedPerson)
      .id(selectedPerson)
}
```

In SwiftUI `@State` determines the identity of a `View` the `init` being called doesn’t mean that that SwiftUI’s storage is being reset.

It is actually meant to outlive the recreation of the `View` which happens all the time.

If you want to reset the storage you have to force it.

Comment: ya know... this absolutely solved it, and I feel silly. I should have thought of this as this is THE way to 100% of the time (and the officially recommended way) to refresh / force a redraw in Flutter, which I spent a few years using (and trying to escape lol). Thanks again. Worked a charm, and bob's the uncle and all that. :)

Comment: @ChrisH glad to help. Just remember  to use id cautiously it is incredibly innefficient. This is one of the few instances where it is justified.

Comment: I don't mind the extra resources; this is a critical-path (employee editor) function, rarely used by very few people, and there will be added inefficiencies as the navigation remains visible and selectable, so I'll also be tracking the "dirty" status of unsaved employees at the parent view so I can do a "whoa there, hoss, stuff's changed. Save it before moving on." alert model. The added resources for all this are a small price to ensure it's 100% functionally robust and correct. ("right" is less important than "correct" in this case). :) Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this by injecting the Person as you do but use `.onChange` instead of `init` to set the properties

So in PersonEditor

```
let person: Person
```

and then the modifier

```
.onChange(of: person, initial: true) { _, newPerson in
    self.edtFirstname = person.firstname
    self.edtLastname = person.lastname
    print("current first name is \(self.edtFirstname)")
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting approach. I have to support iOS down to 15 currently, so the only .onChange(...) version that is available doesn't pick up the initial set as an onChange event at all, which is a kind of interesting (that's mostly annoying). Hmm... I'm trying to cheap out and avoid reworking the parent view or adding some kind of controller. Those can't be my only options. :\

Comment: This answer would absolutely resolve it on iOS versions >= 17. Thanks!

Comment: You can also combine the old style onChange with onAppear