# UIHostingConfiguration breaks @State var

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

I am using `UIHostingConfiguration` to embed SwiftUI Views in a `UICollectionView` like this:

```
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

cell.contentConfiguration = UIHostingConfiguration {
   CellView()
}
```

Any `@State var` declarations in `CellView` or its subviews are being initialized to essentially random values. This seems to completely break the way `@State` works in SwiftUI. I have been able to reproduce it in this pretty simple [sample project](https://github.com/mplorentz/CollectionViewStateDemo). [Here](https://github.com/mplorentz/CollectionViewStateDemo/assets/1165004/900fb15b-98c2-4eaf-ac00-7df42b382055) is a video illustrating the problem. The count for each cell should be initialized to 0, but incrementing the count in any cell causes other cells to display a non-zero count when they are allocated.

I think this happens because when the collection view dequeues a reusable cell it is mem-copying another cell's view and the `@State var` holds the value from the previous cell. This is how collection view cells work in UIKit, but `UICollectionViewCell`s have a `prepareForReuse` function which is supposed to clean up and reinitialize cell state, but I can't fine a similar mechanism in SwiftUI.

**How can I reinitialize `@State var`s in my Views whenever the collection view is dequeuing a cell, and not unnecessarily at other times (like `View.init` which is called much more frequently)?**

EDIT: Ideally I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require code in every SwiftUI View that is in a UIHostingConfiguration, since that will be easy for humans forget.

Comment: You need to store the state somewhere else and pass it to `CellView` through its initialiser or `environment`. As you explained, collection view cells don't have state - you `prepareForReuse` and update the cell with the state it should have, which is stored somewhere else (not in the cell).

Comment: Try using the index or something specific to the cell as the id for the cell  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77548409/swiftui-state-fed-from-struct-building-an-editor/77548639#77548639

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to break UICollectionView's cell reuse by using unique identifiers for every cell like this:

```
let cellReuseID = model.identifier ?? "error"
collectionView.register(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellReuseID)
let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellReuseID, for: indexPath)
```

This ensures `@State` variables play by the rules and are initialized to the value you specify before they are displayed every time. Obviously this incurs a performance cost, but in my case the difference is not noticeable. For me this is preferable to playing whack-a-mole with this bug every time someone adds a @State var to any view in our complex cell hierarchy and forgets about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

`UICollectionViewCell`s are stateless. It is only natural that `@State` doesn't work.

Recall how to set up a collection view cell in UIKit normally - you'd dequeue a cell, and set some property of that cell to something in your model (usually a collection of things), according to the `indexPath` parameter.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    // as an example
    cell.backgroundColor = someColors[indexPath.item]
    
    return cell
}
```

What you are missing here, is `someColors`. Notice that this is not part of the collection view cell, but somewhere else, e.g. as a property in your view controller class. In other words, it is in `cellForItemAt` where you assign all the state to the cell, for it to display. The cell itself does not store that state.

You need to do something similar here. Let's suppose your cells display instances of this:

```
@Observable
class Item {
    var number = 0
}
```

Your cell cannot have state - its initialiser should take an `Item` as a parameter:

```
struct CellView: View {
    
    let item: Item
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Count \(item.number)")
            Button {
                item.number += 1
            } label: {
                Text("Increase count")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Somewhere in your code, you need to store the actual items, e.g.

```
var items = (0..<100).map { _ in Item() }
```

This needs to be passed to somewhere where `cellForItemAt` can easily access. Then all you need to do is:

```
cell.contentConfiguration = UIHostingConfiguration {
    CellView(item: items[indexPath.item])
}
```

I've chosen to use a `class` as an example here because it is easy to pass around. It would be harder if `Item` were a `struct` instead. I'd imagine it's still possible with a `struct`, but that's another story.