How to assign a State var using a Binding var's properties upon view initialization in SwiftUI
Im trying to use properties of @State var and @Binding var variables in the initialization process of my View but I don't really understand if the way im doing it is a conventional or "legit" way of doing it or if it's just that i can't do it the "legit" way because i dont understand how @State var and @Binding var works.
This is what im currently doing
struct EditPrView: View {

    @State var name: String
    @State var nameCount: Int = 0 // Some value just to initalise the variable

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(name)
            Text(String(nameCount))
        }.onAppear(perform: { // Do the "actual" assigment here
            nameCount = name.count
        })
    }
}

This works well (i havent run in to issues yet) but it feels "hacky" and i feel like this should be able to be done in the initialization phase of the view.
This is what i have tried
struct EditPrView: View {

    @State var name: String
    @State var nameCount: Int = name.count // This will throw an error

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(name)
            Text(String(nameCount))
        }
    }
}

This obviously doesn't work and you get a compile time error immediately
class A {
    var a: Int = 0
}

class B: A {
    var b: Int = 5
}

struct EditPrView: View {

    @State private var obj: A?
    @State private var count: Int

    init(obj: A?) {
        self.obj = obj
        if obj is B {
            self.count = 2
        } else {
            self.count = 1
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("foo-bar")
            Text(String(count))
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    var b: A? = B()
    return EditPrView(obj: b)
}

This works fine while im only using @State in a view
class A {
    var a: Int = 0
}

class B: A {
    var b: Int = 5
}

struct EditPrView: View {

    @Binding private var obj: A?
    @State private var count: Int

    init(obj: Binding<A?>) {
        self._obj = obj
        self.count = 0
        if self.obj is B {
            self.count = 2
        } else {
            self.count = 1
        }
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("foo-bar")
            Text(String(count))
        }
    }
}

#Preview {
    @State var b: A? = B()
    return EditPrView(obj: $b)
}

But then i try to add a @Binding var like this and it's like it doesnt even get to the else statement, it just sets self.count to 0 and then continues makes the view appear even if the instance clearly is of type B.
Since i want one way of doing view initialization this has made me stick to the .onAppear(perform: ) way of initalizing variables but as the question asks, is this really the way to do it?
TLDR
Why doesnt the if statement in the last code-block example fire?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77548409/swiftui-state-fed-from-struct-building-an-editor/77548639#77548639

In your final code block, the if does get executed (you can check by using the debugger or adding print statements), but you are trying to update @State multiple times (first to 0 and then to 1 or 2) during init, which is not a supported pattern.
Instead, if you assign it once, it works:
struct EditPrView: View {

    @Binding private var obj: A?
    @State private var count: Int

    init(obj: Binding<A?>) {
        self._obj = obj
        self.count = obj.wrappedValue is B ? 2 : 1
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("foo-bar")
            Text(String(count))
        }
    }
}


You can pass nameCount through in your parent view if you don't want to use your onAppear method:
struct ParentView: View {
  var body: some View {
    EditPrView(
      name: name,
      nameCount: name.count
    )
  }
}

struct EditPrView: View {
    @State var name: String
    @State var nameCount: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(name)
            Text(String(nameCount))
        }
    }
}

Edit: I'd also mention that it doesn't need to be a @Binding unless you're modifying that nameCount value from within EditPtrView and then using that updated value for something else in the parent view. Same with @State, if you aren't modifying those values within the view it doesn't need to be a @State.
Here's what the binding example would look like though if this is what you're trying to do:
struct ParentView: View {
  @State var nameCount: Int = 0
  var body: some View {
    EditPrView(
      name: name,
      nameCount: $nameCount
    )
    .onAppear {
      nameCount = name.count
    }

  }
}

struct EditPrView: View {
    @State var name: String
    @Binding var nameCount: Int

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(name)
            Text(String(nameCount))
        }
    }
}

