Incorrect Carpool ID in ViewModel Fetched Despite Correct Group Being Passed to View
Problem Overview:
I'm working on a SwiftUI app where I need to fetch events for a specific group (carpool). The issue is that the CalendarCell view is not correctly fetching the events for the selected group. Instead, it is always fetching events for a default group despite passing the correct GroupT object (which includes the correct carpool ID) to the view.
Expected Behavior:
When I select a carpool (represented by GroupT), I expect the CalendarCell view to fetch events using the carpool ID of the selected group. However, the carpool ID being used in the EventViewModel does not match the selected group. Instead, it always shows the most recent group. I am using UserDefaults to fetch my carpool id.
CalendarCell View:
struct CalendarCell: View {
    let group: GroupT
    @StateObject var eventViewModel: EventViewModel
    @State private var events: [Event] = []
    @State private var isShowingDailyEventPage = false

    init(group: GroupT) {
        self.group = group
        _eventViewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: EventViewModel(group: group))  // Initialize EventViewModel with selected group
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Some Day")
            .onTapGesture {
                fetchDailyEvents()
            }
    }

   func fetchDailyEvents() {
        guard let carpoolIDString = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "carpoolID") else {
            print("Carpool ID not found in UserDefaults")
            return
        }
        let joinCode = group.joinCode
        printCarpoolID()
        print("Retrieved Carpool ID from UserDefaults: \(carpoolIDString)")

        guard let carpoolID = UUID(uuidString: carpoolIDString) else {
            print("Invalid UUID string for Carpool ID: \(carpoolIDString)")
            return
        }

        print("Valid Carpool ID: \(carpoolID.uuidString)")

        let viewModel = EventViewModel(group: GroupT(carpoolID: carpoolID, carpoolName: "Example", admin: "admin", date_created: Date(), members: [], events: [], joinCode: joinCode))
        
        viewModel.fetchDailyEvents(forCarpoolID: carpoolID.uuidString, date: dateForCell()) { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let events):
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.events = events
                }
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Error fetching events: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }

EventViewModel function:
func fetchDailyEvents(forCarpoolID carpoolID: String, date: Date, completion: @escaping (Result<[Event], Error>) -> Void) {
        // DateFormatter for the date string in ISO 8601 format
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd" // API expects this date format
        let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)

        // Lowercase carpoolID for consistency
        let lowercasedCarpoolID = carpoolID.lowercased()

        // Debugging: Print carpool ID and formatted date
        print("Fetching events for Carpool ID: \(lowercasedCarpoolID) on Date: \(dateString)")

        // Construct the API URL
        guard let apiURL = URL(string: "http://localhost/api/events/\(lowercasedCarpoolID)/date/\(dateString)") else {
            print("Invalid API URL")
            completion(.failure(NetworkError.invalidRequest))
            return
        }

        // Debugging: Print the constructed API URL
        print("Constructed API URL: \(apiURL)")

        // Create URLRequest
        var request = URLRequest(url: apiURL)
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

        // Perform the network request
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            // Handle potential errors
            if let error = error {
                print("Network error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(.failure(NetworkError.invalidResponse))
                return
            }

            // Print the HTTP response status code
            if let httpResponse = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("HTTP Response Status Code: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            }

            // Ensure data is not nil
            guard let data = data else {
                print("No data received")
                completion(.failure(NetworkError.invalidResponse))
                return
            }

            // Debugging: Print the raw JSON response
            if let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                print("Received JSON: \(jsonString)")
            }

            do {
                // Decode the response as an array of Event
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601 // API uses ISO 8601 for date and time

                // Attempt decoding
                let events = try decoder.decode([Event].self, from: data)

                // Debugging: Print the decoded events
                print("Successfully decoded events: \(events)")
                completion(.success(events))
            } catch {
                // Print detailed decoding error information
                print("Decoding error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                completion(.failure(error))
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }

Group Struct:
struct GroupT: Codable {
    let carpoolID: UUID
    let carpoolName: String
    let admin: String
    var members: [String]
    let date_created: Date
    let events: [Event]
    let joinCode: String
}

What I've Tried:

I ensure that the group being passed into CalendarCell is the correct selected group.
I print the carpoolID inside the fetchDailyEvents method to confirm it's correct.
Despite this, the wrong group (the most recent group) is still being used in the view, and events are fetched for the wrong carpool ID(the most recent carpool created).
I ensured that the carpool Ids are being saved in userDefaults correctly they just are being fetched incorrectly.

Question:
How can I ensure that the correct carpool ID is being used when fetching events for a specific group, and why is the EventViewModel not reflecting the selected group’s carpool ID?

You are creating a new EventViewModel object inside the function fetchDailyEvents in the  view, I assume that is a mistake and you should remove that line of code so the property EventViewModel gets used instead

Is that the reason why the wrong carpoolID is being fetched?

You are creating and using an object that doesn’t have the right group.

Oh I see. Can you write me an answer with what to remove so I can accept it for you?

Update: I tried your solution but the same error popped up. It is still fetching the most recent carpool ID rather than the one from the carpool that is clicked

I bet it's because your fetch method reads ID from same UserDefalts variable for any cell, instead of using the one you provided for cell.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77548409/swiftui-state-fed-from-struct-building-an-editor/77548639#77548639


Rename EventsViewModel to EventsFetcher.
Move State Events to published property inside EventsFetcher.
Move fetchDailyEvents in too.
Remove View init and init @StateObject the normal way.

Something like this:
struct CalendarCell: View {
    let group: Group
    @StateObject var eventsFetcher = EventsFetcher() // normal init
    \\ events moved to object
    @State private var isShowingDailyEventPage = false

    // init removed

    var body: some View {
        // display eventsFetcher.events
        Text("Some Day")
            .onTapGesture { [group] in 
                eventsFetcher.fetchDailyEvents(group) // do the fetch
            }
    }
}

class EventsFetcher: ObservableObject {
    @Published var events: [Event] = []

    func fetchDailyEvents(_ group: Group) {
        // fetch events and set on published var, then body will automatically be called.
    }
}


Im not quite sure what you mean could you provide more detail

Sure More detail has been added
